# How can I get older Windows drivers?

Tags: drivers

Sometimes a Windows 10 update installs a new “buggy” driver for a device. So one of the steps I may try (after trying the typical steps, some of them listed below)…is to try installing an older version of the Microsoft driver.

I’d try what I said after the typical: downloading the driver from the manufacturer or reinstalling the driver or rolling it back or removing the update or restoring a restore point…

So I’m thinking of the best way to get and install an older Microsoft driver, these ideas occur to me:

- Boot your PC from an older Windows Installer and robocopy the driverstore folder to another drive (using the installer’s Command Prompt). Then boot Windows and use this copy of the driverstore folder to install the older driver from device manager.
- ..or install the older Windows on another PC and copy the driverstore folder from there..

I may need this in situations like these:
Don't install this Windows 10 update Microsoft just pushed out | TechRadar
https://www.techradar.com/news/dont-install-this-windows-10-update-microsoft-just-pushed-out

Windows 10 update is screwing with drivers — what to do | Tom's Guide
https://www.tomsguide.com/uk/news/windows-10-update-is-screwing-with-drivers-what-to-do

I’d welcome any opinions

Comment: Sometimes the PC manufacturer has drivers for older Windows versions. That may work.

Answer (score 1):

[export-driver](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/dism/export-windowsdriver?view=windowsserver2022-ps)

As you can see in the document,
`dism /online /export-driver/destination:<path>`

It is possible to keep your existing drivers by using the command.
If you do this periodically—even better, after driver updates—and incrementally, you will find that you have outdated drivers.

Sadly, you can only use this method from now on.
If you have a vital need for old drivers, you can specify.